# Show more info (margin, padding, etc.) in Brackets Live Preview

Tags: php, html, css, adobe-brackets

In Brackets Live Preview, when editing the CSS styling of the shown webpage, the selected element in editor is highlighted with blue boundaries in the live web page.

My question is if there is any setting or extension (which I couldn't find) that will show more information about the element on the live preview - for example, the margin, the padding, size in px, etc.

Comment: *bump* - I'm surprised this hasn't been solved yet. I'm also looking for an answer to this almost a year later

Comment: Seems to be a solution [here](http://imgur.com/Gx1r4P3). But I have no idea how to get it working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking the current version of Brackets, the functionality that I asked about is by default implemented in Live Preview mode. The margin and padding of inspected elements are now shown.

Answer (score -1):

If you are unhappy with the browser's native inspector there are addons available such as firebug etc.